# Auto tab in input type text field not working in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, input, ionic-framework

Currently what I'm doing is like this for HTML,

```
 <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" ng-model="user.name" maxlength="1" input-move-next-on-maxlength></input>
 </label>

 <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" ng-model="user.email" maxlength="1" input-move-next-on-maxlength></input>
 </label>
```

and the .js looks like this

```javascript
.directive("inputMoveNextOnMaxlength", function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, element) {
        element.on("label", function(e) {
            if(element.val().length == element.attr("maxlength")) {
                var $nextElement = element.next();
                if($nextElement.length) {
                    $nextElement[0].focus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

})

But, the result is the auto tab is not working. I also tried removing the `<label>`, that worked. I'm wondering does it happen because of the input is at other class or does my code have an error.

Comment: you want to implement auto-tab in mobile devices?

Comment: yes, it worked when i removed this  '<label class="item item-input">' . I need that label because without it, the text box border is disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this solution, It worked for me 
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="autofocus">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="maxLengthReach"></input>
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Title:</label>
    <input autofocus-when></input>
</div>
```

Javascript:
var app = angular.module('autofocus', []);

```
app.directive('autofocusWhen', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('maxLengthReach', function(newValue){
            if (newValue.length >= 5 ) {                                                   
                element[0].focus();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Adjust the length based upon your requirement

Comment: thanks it's worked, but the problem is when I removed this '<label class="item item-input">' , the border of input box is disappear, it seems like the border color is turn to white. i don't have any idea how to resolve this. i had tried so many ways, but it still didn't changed anything.

Comment: thank you so much, i'm already fix my code and it worked like a charm. I'm just add new style color border on it. :D